# sapply function returning null values

Tags: r, function, sapply

I'm studying some basic R programming and doing this sapply exercise raise me the following question, I run the following code but I cannot understand the reason why the NULL values are return.

```
temp <- list(c(3,7,9,6,-1),
         c(6,9,12,13,5),
         c(4,8,3,-1,-3),
         c(1,4,7,2,-2),
         c(5,7,9,4,2),
         c(-3,5,8,9,4),
         c(3,6,9,4,1))

print_info <- function(x) {
  cat("The average temperature is", mean(x), "\n")
}

sapply(temp, print_info)

The average temperature is 4.8 
The average temperature is 9 
The average temperature is 2.2 
The average temperature is 2.4 
The average temperature is 5.4 
The average temperature is 4.6 
The average temperature is 4.6 
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Can you help understand why I get this NULL values?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function has to return something. As demonstrated by  @MichaelChirico that `cat` prints the output in the console and returns `NULL`, those `NULL` are returned as output from `print_info` function.

Instead of using `cat` or `print` in the function, you could use `paste`/`paste0`

```
print_info <- function(x) {
  paste0("\nThe average temperature is ", mean(x))
}

cat(sapply(temp, print_info))

#The average temperature is 4.8 
#The average temperature is 9 
#The average temperature is 2.2 
#The average temperature is 2.4 
#The average temperature is 5.4 
#The average temperature is 4.6 
#The average temperature is 4.6
```

Comment: That definitely returns the expected output, but why 2 outputs are returned with the cat function?

Comment: @JavierFernandez Because 2 outputs are associated with `cat`. One is what is displayed and another one is what is returned. `The average temperature is 4.8` is what is displayed and `NULL` is what is returned from each `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the output of the `cat` function:

```
x = cat('hi\n')
# hi
print(x)
# NULL
```

Comment: My doubt now is, why is that printed after returning the string specified in the body of the function. There's no print function, what's the logic behind returning 2 lists when only 1 is requested?

Comment: @JavierFernandez it is the output of `print(sapply(.))`, Since you didn't assign `sapply` to anything, by default it is run through `print`. If you write `x = sapply(.)` instead, there will be no `NULL` printed. Thus two things are happening: (1) within `sapply`, `cat` is run & produces output for each element of `temp` (2) `print` is applied to the output of `sapply`